# Firefox still asking how to open pdf although preferences are set not to do so

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I wanted to check the download of a pdf with Selenium in firefox, I'm using the following preferences:

```
            var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Windows\\temp");
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application / csv, text / csv, text / plain, application / octet - stream doc xls pdf txt");
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
            firefoxOptions.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
            DriverOptions = firefoxOptions;
```

I know that the preferences are used when I'm running my test because I can see in the browser that the download path is changed to the one I specified and in the popup there is one option less to choose from in handeling the pdf document, the option 'Open with Firefox' is no longer present. But still a popup appears instead of dowloading the pdf document automatically. The popup suggest default to open the pdf document with 'Wondershare'. I have no idea how to solve this problem, is there a preference to get rid of this 'Wondershare' option? I have included an image of the popup, the language is Dutch, the translation of 'Bestand opslaan' is 'Save file to disk'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it a public url so we can test?

Comment: No unfortunately it's not. What can I do to test what you wanted to test?

Comment: Need to know the exact file type so effective `application/*` can be applied.

Comment: It's a normal PDF file. I added a print of the firefox option with preferences for downloading files from the internet. As you can see nothing is said about PDF files. I expect here something like 'Download file' for PDF type files. How can I accomplish this with preference settings for browsertype firefox?.